# Unable to convert a [text/plain,UTF-8] representation into an object of class java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, restlet

I'm facing a strange problem while developing a restlet web service + `Android` app.

When I try to recover a String from the web service (deployed locally on Tomcat 7.0) using a simple get, if the string from the server is too big the Android app crashes with a `NullPointerException`.

Basically, the scheme is the following

*Android app*

```
String retrievedString = clientResource.get();
```

*Web server*

```
return serializedString;
```

When `serializedString` has a (not too) large number of characters (above 2k or something like that), `retrievedString` get a `null` value.

I don't know what is the problem here, but I think the most likely cause is a memory limit, due to Android heap, Java heap, system RAM or maybe even VirtualBox/Genymotion limitation.

What do you think of the problem and how can I solve it?

---

### EDIT

As requested, here it is some more code; I tried to avoid unnecessary stuff and try/catch blocks.

*Server*

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FilterProvider excludeThreadFilter =
        new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("filter properties by name",
            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("email", "password",
                "threads", "messages", "subforumsSet", /*"parentSubforum",
                "registeredDate", "threadSubforum"*/));
    String st = objectMapper.writer(excludeThreadFilter).writeValueAsString(lt);
    return st;
```

*Client*

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("...an ip address...");
    ThreadsInSubforumIdByPage tis = cr.wrap(ThreadsInSubforumIdByPage.class);

      // The line below is null
      String retrievedString = tis.getThreads();
      // The line below raise the NullPointerException
      List<Thread> retrievedList =
        DataHolder.getHolder().getObjectMapper().readValue(
          retrievedString, new TypeReference<List<Thread>>(){});
```

*Exception*

EDIT: Ok, I was misled by logcat color. It's only a few days that I'm using Android Studio and I haven't noticed at all that `Log.e()` messages are written in normal color.

So, this is what logcat reports

```
5 .../W/System.err﹕ Unable to convert a [text/plain,UTF-8] representation into an object of class java.lang.String
5 .../W/System.err﹕ [ 175  3749: 3749 W/System.err ]
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:158)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:525)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.readImpl(SocketChannelImpl.java:305)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at java.nio.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:267)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.ReadableSocketChannel.read(ReadableSocketChannel.java:82)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.connector.Connection$1.read(Connection.java:232)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.fill(Buffer.java:395)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.ReadableBufferedChannel.onFill(ReadableBufferedChannel.java:157)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:601)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.ReadableBufferedChannel.read(ReadableBufferedChannel.java:176)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.fill(Buffer.java:395)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.NbChannelInputStream.onFill(NbChannelInputStream.java:189)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.Buffer.process(Buffer.java:601)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.NbChannelInputStream.read(NbChannelInputStream.java:307)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.BioUtils.copy(BioUtils.java:81)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.io.NioUtils.copy(NioUtils.java:148)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.representation.ReadableRepresentation.write(ReadableRepresentation.java:104)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.representation.ChannelRepresentation.write(ChannelRepresentation.java:76)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.representation.ChannelRepresentation.write(ChannelRepresentation.java:82)
5 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.representation.Representation.getText(Representation.java:397)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.converter.DefaultConverter.toObject(DefaultConverter.java:260)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toObject(ConverterService.java:170)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.resource.Resource.toObject(Resource.java:828)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:240)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at $Proxy23.getThreads(Native Method)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at com.gmail.tigerjack89.pervasive.forum.SubforumContentActivity$LoadThreadsInBackground.loadThreads(SubforumContentActivity.java:329)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at com.gmail.tigerjack89.pervasive.forum.SubforumContentActivity$LoadThreadsInBackground.access$400(SubforumContentActivity.java:283)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at com.gmail.tigerjack89.pervasive.forum.SubforumContentActivity$LoadThreadsInBackground$1.run(SubforumContentActivity.java:301)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
9 .../W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    [ 187  3749: 3749 E/class com.gmail.tigerjack89.pervasive.forum.SubforumContentActivity$LoadThreadsInBackground NullPointerException
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:822)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2153)
            at com.gmail.tigerjack89.pervasive.forum.SubforumContentActivity$LoadThreadsInBackground.loadThreads(SubforumContentActivity.java:331)
            at com.gmail.tigerjack89.pervasive.forum.SubforumContentActivity$LoadThreadsInBackground.access$400(SubforumContentActivity.java:283)
            at com.gmail.tigerjack89.pervasive.forum.SubforumContentActivity$LoadThreadsInBackground$1.run(SubforumContentActivity.java:301)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In the original question, I omitted that I'm using `Jackson` to serialize my entities because seems to be involved only indirectly in this problem. I mean, it raise an `NullPointerException` only when `retrievedString` is null.

---

### AsyncTask code

As requested, here is a lot of code from my AsynkTask

```
  private class LoadThreadsInBackground extends LoadFromServerInBackground
  {
    public LoadThreadsInBackground()
    {
      super(SubforumContentActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Boolean... params)
    {
      runOnUiThread(
        new Runnable()
        {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
            currentThreadsPosition = threadsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            // Appending new data to threadsList
            loadThreads(params[0]);

            // Setting new scroll position
            threadsListView.setSelectionFromTop(currentThreadsPosition + 1, 0);
          }
        });
      return (null);
    }

    private void loadThreads(boolean reload)
    {
      if (reload) threadList.clear();

      ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("IP address");
      cr.setChallengeResponse(getAuthentication());
      ThreadsInSubforumIdByPage tis = cr.wrap(ThreadsInSubforumIdByPage.class);

      List<Thread> retrievedList;
        String s = tis.getThreads();
        retrievedList =
          getObjectMapper().readValue(
            s, new TypeReference<List<Thread>>(){});
      threadList.addAll(retrievedList);

      if ((retrievedList == null) || (retrievedList.size() < Constants
        .RETRIEVED_PER_PAGE))
      {
        loadMoreThreadsButton.setEnabled(false);
        if (retrievedList != null && retrievedList.size() == 0)
        { currentThreadsPage--; }
      }
    }
  }
```

It extends this abstact class

```
public abstract class LoadFromServerInBackground extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, Void>
{
  private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
  private Activity mInvokerActivity;

  public LoadFromServerInBackground(Activity invokerActivity)
  {
    mInvokerActivity = invokerActivity;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
    // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mInvokerActivity);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
  {
    // closing progress dialog
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: If it would be a memory problem, then you will get an corresponding error. Are you sure, that `return serializedString;` really returns something and not `null`? Have you debugged that?

Comment: If it throws NPE on `clientResource.get();` then clearly `clientResource` is null at that point.

Comment: @Tom @CeilingGecko no way guys, I debugged it a couple of time and both `retrievedString` and `clientResource` are not null. Also, if I limit the size of `serializedString` deleting some data, `retrievedString` is not null and android app works fine.

Comment: Well, if they were not null, then you wouldn't get a `NullPointerException`. Can add more code (client and server) and the whole stacktrace?

Comment: another thing that points toward memory problem is that the problem doesn't appear always, but only sometimes, even I don't modify the code at all.

Comment: Did you take a look at line 822 of JsonFActory.java in the code of the matching version of Jackson you are using, for example on grepcode? Which version are you using? If it is 2.4.3, it seems to be indeed the content that is `null`. Did you check androids internal logs around this event?

Comment: @Harald none of the two. 

About Jackson, I haven't tested at all because I don't think it is the problem. I mean, `readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType) ` simply deserialize `content` into a <T> object. But in my code, before the call to `readValue()`, `retrievedString` is yet null and this shouldn't happen. And obviously, whenever I had an exception, I think it is because the `content` is null, as you said yourself. Btw, you're right, I use v2.4.3.
Regarding internal logs, what do you mean? I can't reproduce the problem in this moment, the app doesn't crash anymore in the last hours.

Comment: @Tom @Harald and all the others. I've updated my question; take a look at the exception paragraph. The first line says `Unable to convert a [text/plain,UTF-8] representation into an object of class java.lang.String`

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` Interessting ... check if this is correct for your android application.

Comment: @Tom no way, I'm doing it on an AsyncTask

Comment: @tigerjack89 unfortunately you must be implementing your `AsyncTask` incorrectly, as you can see further up on the stack trace that you're executing on your main thread: `9 .../W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)`. Please post the code for your `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing your `AsyncTask` by calling `runOnUiThread()`. `runOnUiThread()` does exactly what it says it does: executes the code in the `Runnable` on the UI thread.

Network communication on Android must be performed on a background thread, `runOnUiThread()` breaks that requirement.

Try this version of your `AsyncTask`:

```
    private class LoadThreadsInBackground extends LoadFromServerInBackground<List<Thread>> {
    int currentThreadsPosition;
    boolean reload;

    public LoadThreadsInBackground() {
        super(SubforumContentActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        currentThreadsPosition = threadsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Thread> doInBackground(final Boolean... params) {
        reload = params[0];
        // Load data from network
        return loadThreads();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Thread> retrievedList) {
        super.onPostExecute(retrievedList);

        if (reload) {
            threadList.clear();
        }

        // Appending new data to threadsList
        threadList.addAll(retrievedList);

        if ((retrievedList == null) || (retrievedList.size() < Constants.RETRIEVED_PER_PAGE)) {
            loadMoreThreadsButton.setEnabled(false);
            if (retrievedList != null && retrievedList.size() == 0) {
                currentThreadsPage--; 
            }
        }

        threadsListView.setSelectionFromTop(currentThreadsPosition + 1, 0);
    }

    private List<Thread> loadThreads() {
        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("IP address");
        cr.setChallengeResponse(getAuthentication());
        ThreadsInSubforumIdByPage tis = cr.wrap(ThreadsInSubforumIdByPage.class);

        String s = tis.getThreads();
        List<Thread> retrievedList = getObjectMapper().readValue(s, List<Thread>.class);
        return retrievedList;
    }
}
```

Then, have it extend this class:

```
public abstract class LoadFromServerInBackground<T> extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, T> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Activity mInvokerActivity;

    public LoadFromServerInBackground(Activity invokerActivity) {
        mInvokerActivity = invokerActivity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mInvokerActivity);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(T unused) {
        // closing progress dialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great code sddamico, this is gold for me and I'll test it in a while.
Btw, I'm developing Android apps only from some days and I'd like to  better understand your reply: 1) should I avoid using `runOnUiThread()` inside `doInBackground()` NMW? 2) If no, in which case can/would/should I use it? 3) I see that you avoided the call to `setSelectionFromTop()` from AsyncTask. Why? It is related to 2)?